# Saddle point of function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{k}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ differentiable $n$ times.
Assume that $\left(Df\right)_{a}=0$ and $\left(D^2f\right)_{a}=0$ and $\left(D^{3}f\right)\neq0$.
Prove that $a$ is a saddle point.

Comment: I think there are some typos in the question. Also, what is your definition of a saddle point?

Comment: @Max Where are the typos? Its critical point which is minimum or maximum

Comment: The way it's written, $(Df^2)_a=0$ follows from $(Df)_a=0$ by chain rule: $(Df^2)_a=2f(a) (Df)_a=0$. Also $(D^3 f)=0$ without any subscript - and so on all of $\mathbb{R}^k$ - implies that $f$ is a (multivariable) quadratic polynomial, so the third condition is almost always true, and can be made true without changing $f$ near $a$. Finally, did you mean "_not_ a _local_ minimum or a _local_ maximum"? If so, $k=1$, $f(x)=x^4$ and $a=0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: probably meant $(D^2f)_a$

Comment: @Max Yes I meant $D^2f$ and also is *not* minimum or a local maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since as I explained in the comment $f(x)=x^4$ is a counterexample otherwise, I assume you mean $(D^3f)_a\neq 0$.

If $k=1$ we have by Taylor formula $f(x)=f(a)+f'''(a)(a-x)^3+o(|x-a|^3)$. Suppose $f'''(a)>0$; then for $x$ sufficiently close to $a$ we have $f(x)>f(a)$ if $x>a$ and $f(x)<f(a)$ if $x<a$, so $a$ is not a local minimum or nor a local maximum. If $f'''(a)<0$; then again for $x$ sufficiently close to $a$ we have $f(x)>f(a)$ if $x<a$ and $f(x)<f(a)$ if $x>a$, so again $a$ is not a local minimum or nor a local maximum.

Now let $k$ be arbitrary. Since $(D^3f)_a\neq 0$, there exists $v\in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that for the line $\gamma(t)=a+tv$ through $a$ the function $g=f\cdot \gamma$ has $g'''(0)\neq 0$ (otherwise $(D^3f)_a$ is a symmetric trilinear form which vanishes on all triples $(v,v,v)$ for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and so $(D^3f)_a$ must be zero).

Observe that  $g'(0)=(Df)_a \gamma'(0)=0$ and $g''(0)=\gamma'(0)^T (D^2f)_a \gamma(0)=0$. Thus by the case $k=1$ applied to $g$ we have both points with $g(t)>g(0)$ and with $g(t)<g(0)$ arbitrarily near $t=0$. Their images $x=\gamma(t)$ will attain both values $f(x)>f(a)$ and values $f(x)<f(a)$ arbitrarily close to $x$. This means $f$ does not have either a local minimum nor a local maximum at $a$, as wanted.

Comment: Oh thank you very much!

Comment: just another question. How do you delcare g?

Comment: It's in the text: $g$ is the composition of $\gamma$ and $f$ (in other words, it is restriction of $f$ to a line through $a$, where the line is parameterized via $\gamma$).